# SonataMediaBundle: The file "" does not exist 500 Internal Server Error - FileNotFoundException

Tags: symfony-sonata, sonata-admin

I uploaded some files using the SonataMediaBundle but when i wanted to add another, i got that error.

Have you any idea ?

this is the stack error:

```
in /var/www/znata.com/vendor/symfony/symfony/src/Symfony/Component/HttpFoundation/File/MimeType/MimeTypeGuesser.php at line 107  -+

        public function guess($path)
        {
            if (!is_file($path)) {
                throw new FileNotFoundException($path);
            }
            if (!is_readable($path)) {
```

Thanks

Answer (score 8):

Probably caused because your php.ini settings has a max uploaded size set.

Change this to a higher value in your **php.ini**

```
upload_max_filesize = 2M
```

Answer (score 0):

he can't found the file
        if (!is_file($path)) {
            throw new FileNotFoundException($path);
        }

i think you must to reinstanciate the file for the second one

Answer (score 0):

You might face a similar error if you're form doesn't have the attribute: enctype="multipart/form-data"