# SonataMediaBundle: Files/Images not found

Tags: symfony, sonata-media-bundle

I'm using SonataMediaBundle with SonataAdminBundle and Symfony 2.3.

When I try to upload an image via the Sonata Admin interface:

1. Click on "Add New" (`app_dev.php/admin/sonata/media/media/create`)
2. Click on "Image" (`app_dev.php/admin/sonata/media/media/create?provider=sonata.media.provider.image&context=default`)
3. Browse the `image.jpg` file and click on "create"
4. This leads me to the edit page where I can see: `Item "image.jpg" has been successfully created.`

And indeed:

- In the folder `web\uploads\media\default\0001\01` I have my image file and the 3 thumbs
- In the `media__media` DB table I have the corresponding line
- When I browse `web/uploads/media/default/0001/01/` with Firefox I can see my image
- The corresponding line appears in the media list (in admin panel)

**But**:

- The image is not displayed in the media list (there is a square instead of the thumb) nor in the image edit page (`app_dev.php/admin/sonata/media/media/3/edit?provider=sonata.media.provider.image&context=default`)

---

For the files, it's even worse:

1. Click on "Add New" (`app_dev.php/admin/sonata/media/media/create`)
2. Click on "Image" (`app_dev.php/admin/sonata/media/media/create?provider=sonata.media.provider.file&context=default`)
3. Browse the `document.zip` file and click on "create"

This generates the error 500: `The file "" does not exist`. And no new line is created in the DB.

---

**Piece of solution**

For the image problem, I noticed that the path where sonata admin was looking was not the good one: I it looking in: `http://myserver/uploads/media/default/0001/01/c35f187f1b405f4bfba8b962d83e5bbdccff54f9.jpeg`

Instead of `http://myserver/myproject/web/uploads/media/default/0001/01/c35f187f1b405f4bfba8b962d83e5bbdccff54f9.jpeg`

Apparently, this is due to this part of the config.yml (as defined in SonataMedia documentation):

```
sonata_media
    cdn:
        server:
            path: /uploads/media
```

That I replaced by:

```
sonata_media
    cdn:
        server:
            path: /myproject/web/uploads/media
```

And it works. But I don't think it's a good idea to hardcode this there. And I guess that there is a good reason why it it written this way in the Sonata Doc, no?

**Is my modification correct? If not, how should I do?**

In any case, it doesn't solve my file uploading problem! **Any idea on this point?**

Comment: I have the exact same problem. Have you found a solution yet?

Comment: is the target directory got sufficent writable permissions for apache or nginx ?

Answer (score 3):

> The file "" does not exist

As explained [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/22150837/1585128), this is caused by insufficient limit for allowed upload file size in php.ini (increase `upload_max_filesize` and `post_max_size`).

Then you will probably stumble on another error saying that the zip file type is not allowed, so add this into your config.yml:

```
sonata_media:   
    providers:
        file:
            allowed_extensions: ['zip']
```

Answer (score 0):

```
sonata_media
    cdn:
        server:
            path: /myproject/web/uploads/media
```

This is the working option.
I don't think there is a problem to hard code this.